# How to prove that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1) e^{-\frac{k^2}{2}} < 3$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What could be a possible approach to find the sum of this series $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1) e^{-\frac{k^2}{2}}$ (the sum or an estimate of the sum)?  Any answer will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little messy but not too hard to show that

$${4\over e^{9/2}}+{5\over e^{16/2}}+{6\over e^{25/2}}+\cdots={4\over e^4}\left({1\over e^{1/2}}+{5/4\over e^4}+{6/4\over e^{17/2}}+\cdots \right)\lt{4\over e^4}\lt{4\over40}={1\over10}$$

It follows that

$$1+{2\over e^{1/2}}+{3\over e^2}+{4\over e^{9/2}}+\cdots\lt1+{2\over\sqrt2}+{3\over7}+{1\over10}={107\over70}+\sqrt2\lt3$$

where the final inequality can be verified from the equivalence

$${107\over70}+\sqrt2\lt3\iff107+70\sqrt2\lt210\iff70\sqrt2\lt103$$

and the easy calculation

$$(70\sqrt2)^2=9800\lt10{,}000=100^2\lt103^2$$

Remarks: We use the inequalities $2\lt e$ and $7\lt e^2$ (so that $40\lt e^4$) in obvious spots in the comparisons. These also help in the "messy" comparison

$${1\over e^{1/2}}+{5/4\over e^4}+{6/4\over e^{17/2}}+\cdots\lt{1\over e^{1/2}}\left(1+{1\over e^2}+{1\over e^4}+\cdots \right)={1\over\sqrt e}{1\over1-{1\over e^2}}\lt{1\over\sqrt2}{1\over1-{1\over7}}={7\over6\sqrt2}\lt1$$

A more challenging problem might be to show that

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1)e^{-k^2/2}\lt e$$

Comment: This is the kind of approach I was going to suggest in a comment. The series converges faster than any positive geometric series so after a few terms we can get a crude but useful upper bound on the sum of the remaining terms by comparing the remainder to some geometric series.

Comment: My answer would have been:$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1) e^{-\frac{k^2}{2}}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}k e^{-\frac{k^2}{2}}+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{k^2}{2}}\lt\int\limits_0^\infty xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{k}{2}}$

so

$\big(-e^{-\frac{k^2}{2}}\big)_0^\infty +\frac{1}{1-1/\sqrt{e}}\lt2,542..$

Comment: @JV.Stalker, Are you sure the integral is larger than the corresponding sum? The function $xe^{-x^2/2}$ is not strictly decreasing on all of $\mathbb{R}^+$. (The sum of the first three terms of the series is approximately $2.62$, which is already bigger than $2.542$.)

Comment: @Barry Cipra, your question is rightfull, there shoud be an extreme value in $\mathbb{R}^+$. Let me check this.  Thank you for your notice.

Comment: @JV.Stalker, also, I get $2.542$ just from $1/(1-1/\sqrt e)$. I get another $1$ from the integral. So even if the integral *does* bound the corresponding sum, the total is bigger than $3$.

Comment: @JV.Stalker, I think you *can* make your (actually very nice!) approach work, but I think you need to pick off the first two or three terms and start the bounding comparisons at $k=3$ or $4$.

Comment: @Barry Cipra I am sorry for the late answer I could not be at my computer but thanks for the last advice. I start to deal with the exercise again.Best regards,